# rearranging ggplot axis groups in plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to rearrange my plot such that it follows the correct confusion matrix structure from the `caret` package.

For example, I have the following confusion matrix table:

```
Prediction    0    1
         0 3444  265
         1   98  148
```

Where the `1` is the `bankrupt` case and the `0` is the `Non-Bankrupt` case in my data. I seem to have my data the opposite of what I want it to look like.

Other confusion matrix:

```
          Reference
Prediction    0    1
         0 3317  313
         1   87  164

          Reference
Prediction    0    1
         0 3079  308
         1   78  182

          Reference
Prediction    0    1
         0 2980  335
         1  106  144
```

I want to rearrange the plots such at (for the first confusion matrix) the `3444` number and points are in the upper quadrant with the text "Non-Bankrupt" next to it (which is the `0` in the confusion matrix). The `148` should be in the bottom right quadrant. The `265` should be in the upper right quadrant and the `98` should be in the bottom left quadrant. (Just as displayed in the first confusion matrix)

Code:

```
d %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = pred_status, y = status, color = correct)) +
  geom_jitter() +
  geom_text(aes(label = n), size = 15, color = "black", family = "serif") +
  facet_wrap(~Model_Name) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Non-Bankrupt", "Bankrupt")) +
  scale_y_discrete(labels = c("Non-Bankrupt", "Bankrupt"))
```

Sample of the data:

```
d <- structure(list(pred_status = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), status = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    correct = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Correct", 
    "Incorrect"), class = "factor"), n = c(2980L, 2980L, 313L, 
    3444L, 2980L, 3444L, 3444L, 2980L, 3317L, 2980L, 3317L, 3317L, 
    182L, 3317L, 3079L, 2980L, 3444L, 3444L, 3317L, 3079L, 3079L, 
    144L, 3444L, 3444L, 3079L, 2980L, 2980L, 3444L, 3444L, 3317L, 
    3444L, 3444L, 2980L, 3444L, 3317L, 3079L, 3079L, 3079L, 3444L, 
    2980L, 3317L, 3444L, 3444L, 3317L, 144L, 3079L, 2980L, 2980L, 
    3317L, 3079L, 182L, 335L, 3444L, 3317L, 3444L, 3444L, 3444L, 
    106L, 3079L, 3317L, 3079L, 3079L, 3444L, 3444L, 3079L, 164L, 
    3444L, 2980L, 3079L, 2980L, 3079L, 164L, 3317L, 3317L, 2980L, 
    148L, 313L, 3444L, 3079L, 3317L, 3444L, 3079L, 3444L, 3317L, 
    3444L, 3444L, 3079L, 3444L, 3317L, 3079L, 144L, 3079L, 3317L, 
    3317L, 3079L, 3317L, 3444L, 2980L, 3317L, 2980L, 3444L, 2980L, 
    3079L, 3079L, 3444L, 3444L, 2980L, 3317L, 3317L, 2980L, 3079L, 
    98L, 3079L, 3444L, 3444L, 2980L, 3317L, 3079L, 3444L, 2980L, 
    3079L, 3317L, 144L, 182L, 3317L, 3079L, 2980L, 3079L, 3444L, 
    313L, 2980L, 3317L, 3444L, 3317L, 3317L, 3079L, 2980L, 3444L, 
    182L, 3079L, 3317L, 3444L, 265L, 164L, 335L, 3079L, 2980L, 
    2980L, 3444L, 3079L, 3444L, 2980L, 3317L, 148L, 3444L, 2980L, 
    3079L, 3444L, 3079L, 2980L, 3317L, 3444L, 2980L, 98L, 3317L, 
    78L, 3317L, 2980L, 3079L, 106L, 3079L, 3079L, 3079L, 2980L, 
    2980L, 3317L, 2980L, 3444L, 3444L, 3079L, 2980L, 3444L, 3079L, 
    2980L, 3317L, 3317L, 164L, 308L, 3317L, 3444L, 313L, 3444L, 
    3317L, 3444L, 2980L, 3317L, 3317L, 3444L, 2980L, 3444L), 
    Model_Name = c("4 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", "1 Year", "4 Year", 
    "1 Year", "1 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", 
    "2 Year", "3 Year", "2 Year", "3 Year", "4 Year", "1 Year", 
    "1 Year", "2 Year", "3 Year", "3 Year", "4 Year", "1 Year", 
    "1 Year", "3 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "1 Year", "1 Year", 
    "2 Year", "1 Year", "1 Year", "4 Year", "1 Year", "2 Year", 
    "3 Year", "3 Year", "3 Year", "1 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", 
    "1 Year", "1 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", "3 Year", "4 Year", 
    "4 Year", "2 Year", "3 Year", "3 Year", "4 Year", "1 Year", 
    "2 Year", "1 Year", "1 Year", "1 Year", "4 Year", "3 Year", 
    "2 Year", "3 Year", "3 Year", "1 Year", "1 Year", "3 Year", 
    "2 Year", "1 Year", "4 Year", "3 Year", "4 Year", "3 Year", 
    "2 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", "1 Year", "2 Year", 
    "1 Year", "3 Year", "2 Year", "1 Year", "3 Year", "1 Year", 
    "2 Year", "1 Year", "1 Year", "3 Year", "1 Year", "2 Year", 
    "3 Year", "4 Year", "3 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", "3 Year", 
    "2 Year", "1 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", "1 Year", 
    "4 Year", "3 Year", "3 Year", "1 Year", "1 Year", "4 Year", 
    "2 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", "3 Year", "1 Year", "3 Year", 
    "1 Year", "1 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", "3 Year", "1 Year", 
    "4 Year", "3 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", "3 Year", "2 Year", 
    "3 Year", "4 Year", "3 Year", "1 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", 
    "2 Year", "1 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", "3 Year", "4 Year", 
    "1 Year", "3 Year", "3 Year", "2 Year", "1 Year", "1 Year", 
    "2 Year", "4 Year", "3 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "1 Year", 
    "3 Year", "1 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", "1 Year", "1 Year", 
    "4 Year", "3 Year", "1 Year", "3 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", 
    "1 Year", "4 Year", "1 Year", "2 Year", "3 Year", "2 Year", 
    "4 Year", "3 Year", "4 Year", "3 Year", "3 Year", "3 Year", 
    "4 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", "1 Year", "1 Year", 
    "3 Year", "4 Year", "1 Year", "3 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", 
    "2 Year", "2 Year", "3 Year", "2 Year", "1 Year", "2 Year", 
    "1 Year", "2 Year", "1 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", 
    "1 Year", "4 Year", "1 Year")), row.names = c(NA, -200L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried and came up with this minor changes:

```
    library(tidyverse)
    d %>% 
        ggplot(aes(x = status, y = fct_rev(pred_status), color = correct)) +
        geom_jitter() +
        geom_text(aes(label = n), size = 15, color = "black", family = "serif") +
        facet_wrap(~Model_Name) +
        scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Non-Bankrupt", "Bankrupt")) +
        scale_y_discrete(labels = c("Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt"))
```

Which gives me this figure:

[image]

Not 100% sure if the labels are correct now?è